# R Mean Subtraction For Groups

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, mean

```
data=data.frame(SCORE=c(9,9,10,7,10,10,8,10,9,5,10,7,9,4,9,8,3,6,4,5,10,10,6,9,5,8,3,7,5,6,7,4,8,7,10,6,9,7,8,8,9,9,4,5,6,6,7,10,8,6),
TYPE=c(0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0),
GRADE=c(2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,3,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2,2,2,3,2,3,2,2,1,1,2,2,3,3,1,2,3,3,3,2,2,3,2,2,3,3,3,2,1),
SCHOOL=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,2))
```

If you have this sample data and wish to get it in to this format:

[image]

For EVERY 'GRADE' and 'SCHOOL' I wish to get the mean value of 'SCORE' for 'TYPE' equals to 1 and subtract it away from the mean value of 'SCORE' for 'TYPE' equals to 0.

In the data table format you can put
data[, SCORESUBTRACT := sum(SCORE)/nrow(data), by = list(GRADE, SCHOOL)] but is it possible to get the subtraction for 'TYPE' equals to 1 from 'TYPE' equals to 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>% group_by(GRADE,SCHOOL,TYPE) %>% summarise(Val=mean(SCORE,na.rm=T)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = TYPE,values_from = Val) %>%
  mutate(Diff=`1`-`0`)

# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   GRADE, SCHOOL [6]
  GRADE SCHOOL   `0`   `1`    Diff
  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1      1  7     6.75 -0.25  
2     1      2  7.75  7.8   0.0500
3     2      1  7.57  8     0.429 
4     2      2  6.5   7.67  1.17  
5     3      1  6.5   6.75  0.25  
6     3      2  5.67  7.67  2
```

Comment: @bvowe Oh sorry, I am not expert at using `data.table` but `dplyr` is a great option too!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a data.table solution for you. Hope it works well.

First lets read the same data as a data.table directly and set the key as grade and school

```
data=data.table(SCORE=c(9,9,10,7,10,10,8,10,9,5,10,7,9,4,9,8,3,6,4,5,10,10,6,9,5,8,3,7,5,6,7,4,8,7,10,6,9,7,8,8,9,9,4,5,6,6,7,10,8,6),
                TYPE=c(0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                GRADE=c(2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,3,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2,2,2,3,2,3,2,2,1,1,2,2,3,3,1,2,3,3,3,2,2,3,2,2,3,3,3,2,1),
            SCHOOL=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,2))
setkeyv(data , c("GRADE","SCHOOL"))
```

Now we calculate the mean score like you had and then go forward with calculating the updated score as you wanted it

```
data[ , MeanScore:= mean(SCORE) , by = key(data)]
data[ TYPE == 0 , updated_score := SCORE - MeanScore ]
data[ TYPE == 1 , updated_score := MeanScore ]
```